# Greater than inputText javascript validator

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, jsf

I have 2 inputTexts, one to set the upper limit and another to set the lower limit (numeric).

The view: (code and under code the capture of the element seen when I press F12)

```
<h:form id="form">
```

[image]

```
<h:inputText id="lowerLmt" styleClass="input-sm form-control required number    
 minlim" value="#{managedBean.min}"/>
```

[image]

```
<h:inputText id="upperLmt" styleClass="input-sm form-control maxlim"
 value="#{managedBean.max}"/>
```

[image]

```
</form>
```

According to this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/2hA8M/8/) I have defined the validator:

```
$.validator.addMethod("upper_limit_greater_than_lower_limit", function(){
return $('#upperLmt').val() >= $('#lowerLmt').val()
}, "The upper limit mut be grater than or equal to lower limit");
```

And I tried to validate the form:

```
$('#form').validate({
   rules: {
       upperLmt: {
           required: true,
           upper_limit_greater_than_lower_limit: true
       },
       lowerLmt: {
           requred: true,
           upper_limit_greater_than_lower_limit: true
       },
   }, 
});
```

I see the ids of my imputTexts are **form:id** because I use jsf components.
If I try to validate the form witform:id I have errors
   [image]

What should I do to make this validator to work?

Answer (score 0):

because this is not a valid object.
It should be

```
rules: {
  form: { upperLmt: { .. },
          lowerLmt: { .. }
  }
}
```

.. that doesn't mean your code will work.. it's only a hint to fix your syntax issue